# Adding html between Angular Material 2 table rows

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I would like to add html markup between the rows of my md-table (Angular-Material 2).

The idea being that when a row is clicked additional information can slide out beneath the row within a div.

After reading the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) I can't quite work out if this is possible. Does anyone have any idea if this could be done?

Comment: There is a Github issue https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5936 for this feature.

And a solution proposed is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZL6OnWwVmOCPYetp96XX?p=preview